# Event only firing once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that checks for a value and if it is equal to '' then an message is shown to the user. This works ok. But I seem to have 2 issues with the code.

Firstly, when I run the code the first time it works fine. But if I run it again, nothing happens. I have to refresh the page to run again.

Secondly, my button is type submit and even though I have e.preventDefault(); in the code, it submits and it shouldn't be doing that.

I would grateful if someone could point out my error and help me move forward. Many thanks

```
html
<button type="submit" id="retrieve" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve</button>


$("#USRboxrtv").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var activity = $("#user").val();
      var service = $("#activityRadios").val();
      var dept = $("#rtvdept").val();

      if (dept == "") {
        $("#deptmessage").html('You must enter a department').css({
          'color': 'red',
          'font-size': '14px'
        }).fadeOut(2000);

        return false;
      }

      var data = $("#USRboxrtv").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/lstor/users/requests/boxes/retrieve/brtv.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          {
            $('.message').html(data).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            $("#USRboxrtv").get(0).reset();
            $("#box_rtv").load("refreshBox.php");
            $("#rtvdept").trigger("chosen:updated");
            $("#address").trigger("chosen:updated");
            $("#box_rtv_chosen").find('option:selected').remove();
            $("#box_rtv").html('');
            $("#box_rtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: `#USRboxrtv` is a form element?

Comment: @Teemu yes that is correct. Thanks

Comment: Where is your `click event`, `alert` codes?

Comment: @Sajib what click event? I am using submit to check and serialize. Should I also have click event? Thanks

Comment: I think @Sajib refers to when you said "then an alert is triggered to the user"

Comment: got it ... `"You must enter a department"` is the alert actually. I thought `alert()`!

Comment: Oh my bad. I shall amend post to reflect message div. Thanks

Comment: Made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ugk8jt3k/1/ and everything looks like is working.

Comment: @mplungjan Changed type to button and it dosen't fire at all. It only submits if 'dept' holds a value, which is correct? Thanks

Comment: @Troyer Your code triggers as it should. Where is the difference. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I meant: Change to button and then  `$("#retrieve").click` instead of `$("#USRboxrtv").submit`

Comment: But still: If the form submits when you have an empty dept with your code, then the code is not executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you called function [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), the element will be hidden until you show it again.
So you need to call the function [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) before fade it out.

See following please:

```js
$("#retrieve").ready(function(){

  $("#USRboxrtv").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#deptmessage").html('You must enter a department').css({
        'color': 'red',
        'font-size': '14px'
      }).show().fadeOut(2000);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="deptmessage">

</div>
<form id="USRboxrtv">
  <button type="submit" id="retrieve" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Working. Now on to the next problem. LOL